# Can't use the name of Gd during spontaneous prayer?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemos-sacred-names

What is the rationale in suggesting that a person who wishes to pray to Hashem outside the context of formal communal prayer, that they may not use Gd's name in doing so?

This seems to me to go against most of the examples of prayer we find in Tanach and the Talmud, as well as Chasidic custom.

---

[Inspired by this question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13326/597)

Comment: Where have you seen such a suggestion?

Comment: In the question I linked to...

Comment: I think that that question is referring only to _sh'mone esre_.

Comment: Seems to be saying that mentioning Gd's name many many times is an issue.

Comment: I agree that it is unclear what the linked questioner meant by "many many times".  AFAIK, women can pray any or all of the three daily prayer services, if they so choose (and according to Rambam and others, women have an actual obligation to engage in some form of prayer daily).  If "many many times" means shemoneh esreh, it's not an issue.  If it means personal prayer (hisbodedus, informal voluntarily prayer etc). - I don't know of anyone who says Ado-shem during that.  G-d, Hashem, Father, Abba, L-rd, are more commonly used - but I don't have a source that forbids use of Ado-shem for this.

Comment: but in any case, the above sub-questions I posed (and their corresponding answers, whoever finds them) should not be gender-dependent.

Comment: In the question linked to, I meant that mentioning Gd's name when you don't have to is a potential danger, if you do not have kavonnoh. There are two traditions of prayer - the spontaneous and the formal (see Chief Rabbi Sacks introduction to the Siddur). IMHO the spontaneous is much less likely to suffer from problems of kavonnoh. The mispallel is crying out to his Creator in a moment of need. He will have kavonnoh!

Comment: @Will, at least some people say _Hashem_'s name in the short prayers said with the _simanim_ eaten _lel R"H_, and even do so for made-up _simanim_ and accompanying made-up prayers.

Comment: @msh210 point taken, but I've still never heard of someone using Ado-shem in a personal conversation / prayer with our Creator.

Comment: @Will how would you?  To everyone ... some of these comments could be answers!

Comment: @avi I usually say G-d.  Everyone should say whatever is most comfortable for them.

Comment: Do you have a source that there was a chassidic custom to spontanuously daven using Hashem's Name (rather than a kinui like Aibishter or Ribbono Shel Olam)?

Comment: @commentator  What is the difference between saying "master of the world" , and "my lord", or "our Gd"... Nobody is pronouncing the unpronounceable.

Comment: @avi according to the teachings of the Arizal, when one pronounces Ado-shem with the kavana that one is saying it in place of Y-K-V-K it is literally as if one had actually pronounced Y-K-V-K.

Comment: @yoel great so acording to the Arizal's teachings we are now all guilty of karet

Comment: I suspect you are understanding the teaching incorrectly

Comment: @avi there's obviously a difference between saying G-d's Name verbally and saying It according to kabala.

Comment: @yoel I'm asking a question here about not being allowed to say Gd's name while praying spontaneously.  Please don't get lost from the context of the comments.

Comment: @avi right, and you contended that Ado-shem is no different from Ribono shel Olam. According to Kabala this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that it is entirely permissible;

> It is permissible, however, to invoke the Name of *Hashem* to praise or to give thanks to Him.  Similarly, it is permissible to call on the Name of *Hashem* in the context of private supplication. The familiar יהי רצון מלפנך ה' אלקינו as a prelude to prayer is acceptable and does not constitute uttering the Name of *Hashem* in vain (Rabbi Forst, The Laws of B'rachos, p. 48, with the footnote "*Tosfos Chaim* on *Chayei Adam* 5:7 citing the *Magen Avraham* 188:11. See *Sefer Chassidim* cited in M.B. 5:3")

(I believe that the issue in the question referenced is not, strictly speaking, one of a *beracha l'vatala* (a blessing in vain) but rather a *berachah sh'aina tzirchah* (an unnecessary blessing, using G-d's name in a formal blessing which was redundant or not obligatory), see ibid, page 55 for a better presentation.)

Comment: What is the difference between a formal blessing which is not needed, and a private supplication?  And why do you think the difference bewtween bracha l'vatal and beracha sh'aina tzirchah is relevant?