# Women and Tefillah - per the Rav

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women, sources-mekorot, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

I remember a long time ago hearing that [the Rav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) (Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik (1903–1993)) held that women should pray three times a day.

Can anyone verify this, and what is the reason/source for this?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/what-is-a-womans-obligation-when-it-comes-to-tfillah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As quoted in MiPeninei HaRav (page 73), the Rav felt 'based on the simple reading of the Mishna in Berachot ([20](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=37&size=1)b)' that women are obligated to pray Maariv.