# Is a woman allowed to pray maariv?

Tags: tefilla, women, maariv

I have heard that, according to the letter of the law, women only need to pray once a day (usually shachris). Some women add an additional prayer which is usually mincha.

If a woman desired to, could she pray three times just like men do: Shachris, Mincha and Maariv? Or is discouraged for women to pray Maariv?

Comment: highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/what-is-a-womans-obligation-when-it-comes-to-tfillah

Comment: See here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16074/5

Comment: Very closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16059/5

Comment: What you heard is a highly controversial position which wasn't held or even presented as a possibility by anyone until the 17th century. The apparent unanimous position of everyone till then is that women should pray Shemoneh Esrei just like men, and such continues to be the dominant traditional position espoused by the vast majority of later authorities.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no question that an Ashkenazi woman can pray maariv if she desires.**

It has optional status according to many, [R Melamed for instance writes](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=3758)

> Women never took Maariv upon themselves. Therefore, Maariv
>   retains the status of an optional prayer for women.

Since a woman needs to pray once a day at least, he later writes that

> If a woman was unable to pray both Shacharit and Mincha she should
>   nonetheless pray Maariv.

R Doniel Neustadt writes [here](http://www.torah.org.il/advanced/weekly-halacha/5772/vaera.html)

> Note that all tefilos in which women may be exempt, such as the daily
>   **Ma'ariv** [...] **are still permitted to be davened by women**. [**However one
>   should ask a rav for sefardic women**] since some Sephardic poksim
>   (e.g., Yechaveh Da'as 1:68; 3:3) rule that women are not allowed to
>   daven certain parts of the davening from which they are exempt.

According to [R Yosef Ber Soloveichik](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16074/11501), maariv has obligatory status for women.

See also [here](https://www.jofa.org/sites/default/files/uploaded_files/10002_u/00861.pdf) for more sources.

Comment: You would do well to clarify what "optional" means, as I've met many who regularly misunderstand that term. "Optional" here (at least according to the vast majority of Rishonim, including Tosfot, Rif, Rosh/Tur (and possibly the Rambam) and seemingly the Beit Yosef who cites this and no dissenters) means that it can be pushed off in extenuating circumstances like being busy with another time-sensitive Mitzva, not that you can skip it willy-nilly. This is the ruling of the Mishna Berura (OC 107 sk 2, 237 sk 1).

Comment: R Melamed cites no source for his claims in that article. Indeed, even if he is echoing some late Acharon's speculation, the claim is quite dubious, as no sources contemporary to the acceptance mention gender. (The Rambam writes "נהגו **כל ישראל** בכל מקומות מושבותיהם", the Rif "והאידנא נהוג עלמא לשוייה כחובה", the Rosh "והאידנא נהוג עלמא בתפלת ערבית מנהג חובה", and the ShA/Rama omit any details of the rules of the Reshut status because they aren't relevant anymore.) Of course, R Melamed's omission of any reference to those who obligate women in Maariv makes his article further suspect.

Comment: Mahari Weill 193 in the early 15th century says women should be careful not to do melacha sat night before they daven _but_ if they don't know how to daven they should be taught to say baruch hamavdil. Clearly, at the time women hadn't yet never accepted maariv...

Comment: @Double AA Mishna Berura 106:4 writes “ אבל תפלת ערבית שהוא רשות אע"פ שעכשיו כבר קבלוהו עליהם כל ישראל לחובה מ"מ הנשים לא קבלו עליהם ורובן אין מתפללין ערבית.” This is what Rav Melamed is probably referring to. Also see https://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/women-and-maariv/  who cites the Graz 106:2; Mishnah Berurah 106:4; cf. Magen Avraham 299:16) as saying that women do not need to daven maariv. Which contemporary poskim hold that women must daven maariv besides the AHS?

Comment: @Eman I'm skeptical. The Mishna Berura (like literally all ashkenazi rishonim and acharonim ever) as above holds that the only possible reason for anyone to not daven arvit is if you have a pressing other mitzva that needs to be done, unlike what R' Melammed writes. Even if that's what R' Melammed is misrepresenting, it doesn't change the fact that the historical claim is quite dubious, to say it politely. It's beyond me why anyone takes this seriously. Chas veshalom to teach it to your holy daughters.

Comment: @Eman Besides the Aruch haShulchan and R' Soloveitchik? There's R Binyonim Zilber (Az Nidbru [12:65](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=885&st=&pgnum=118)) and R' Yitzchak Abadi to throw out some names from different parts of Orthodox Judaism (Litvish, Modern Orthodox, Charedi, Sefardi). The old ashkenazi minhag was always this way as seen in Mahari Weill above, Meshivat Nafesh (Beshalach), Yefeh Nof (#42) and more. Only recently in the last century or so did the illiteracy of some women become institutionalized to create a new unprecedented practice to voluntarily (!) not pray nightly

Comment: There is no question historically that "women never accepted maariv" is factually wrong. Even without all those testimonies of women praying three times daily, it used to be obvious that the theoretical reshut status of maariv was irrelevant to all; that's why it isn't discussed it in Shulchan Aruch since it's irrelevant. Only much later did people start discussing detailed questions like https://mi.yodeya.com/a/57741/ No rabbi had a woman who doesn't daven maariv forget mincha until the 20th century??? C'mon.

Comment: You can try to argue women's acceptance was nullified only recently by women choosing not to follow it? Good luck, I guess. You'd still have the overwhelming dominant position in Rishonim and Acharonim (and the universal position among ashkenazi authorities AFAIK) that without such an acceptance you can still only skip praying for some other pressing need. That these women can so easily dismiss such a large cadre of our Sages is breathtakingly scary. Stop going to a challah baking group and start praying the way God intended!

Comment: @Eman I hate to say it but that article by R' Kaganoff is embarrassing. He asserts that the "dispute" between the aruch hashulchan and MB about women davening maariv is based on the "dispute" between tosfot and the rif respectively if maariv is basically obligatory. This is definitely mistaken since the MB (like every ashkenazi authority I have ever seen) explicitly in multiple places rules like tosafot!!! How could he skip that detail? Plus the Magen Avraham he cites only says many women wouldn't pray on Saturday nights, which implies (see Machatzit Hashekel/PMG) they otherwise prayed nightly