# Can a man who has undergone sex change give his wife a Get?

Tags: halacha-theory, women, medicine, divorce, gender-identity

If a married Jewish man undergoes the hormonal and surgical procedure of sex change, and "he's become a woman".

1. Would he still have the Halachic status of a man, at least relating to his marital status?
2. Could he give his wife a Get if he wanted to?
3. Would he be deemed by Halachah as mentally competent to give the Get?

Comment: would he also be patur in mitzva zman gerama like a woman? dont think so. being a man is not just a physical thing. the souls are different.

Comment: I seem to recall that the Tzitz Eliezer rules that sex changes work halachically to change one's gender (though they're assur lechatchila), while some other poskim rule that they do not change one's halachic gender. So it would seem like the problem is only according to the shita of the Tzitz Eliezer.

Comment: @ray Who said souls are perfectly correlated to chiyuv mitzvot? If someone concludes a man accidentally got a woman's soul, he's now patur?

Comment: @DoubleAA *Or HaChaim* (*B'reishis* 22:20 and elsewhere) comments that Yitzchak was born with a female soul, and he did not receive a male soul (that would allow him to get married and have children) until the *akeida*. This idea may trace to the Zohar (see for example *Pikudei* 257a in light of 227b, מסטרא דשמאלא מסטרא דנוקבא). The רמ"ע מפאנו also describes Yitzchak as having a soul "from the side of femininity" (*Gilgulei N'shamos* 90:2), and the *Seder HaDoros* (*Elef HaRishon*) writes that Yitzchak was a *gilgul* of Chava.

Comment: would the halacha be different than if the man had castrated himself (not that I know the halacha in that case)?

Comment: @Menachem A סריס אדם can give a Get (ShA EH 172:3). I thus don't see any reason to suspect that by doing that he would thereby become a women.

Answer (score 11):

According to the majority of poskim, he is a man despite whatever surgery he had and he would certainly be allowed to give his wife a get. According to the minority view of the Tzitz Eliezer, he would not have to give his wife a get, because the marriage dissolved when he "became a woman."

He obviously does not meet the qualifications for a Shoteh. 
See R. Bleich, Contemporary Halakhic Problems, vol. 1, p. 100ff.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you could cite your sources.  Can you give some examples of poskim who hold by the majority?  Where does the Tzitz Eliezer say what he said?

Comment: See R. Bleich, Contemporary Halakhic Problems, vol. 1, p. 100ff.

Comment: His genetic makeup will always remain male regardless of how convincing his gender change is. His genetic material will remain XY(male) and he will never have a genotype of XX (female). I would also favor an answer that he can give her a get.

Comment: "*He obviously does not meet the qualifications for a shoteh*" ....not so obvious to me....

Comment: See [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34058/how-is-gender-halachically-determined#comment140528_34060) and the subsequent one. Contrary to the oft-misrepresented portrayal of the *Tzitz Eliezer*'s view, he holds (like every other halachic source) that surgery cannot change a man into a woman. He merely considers the possibility (without arriving at a conclusion) that an infertile *androginus* could become a woman through surgery.

Comment: @Fred my recollection is that the Tzitz Eliezer was willing to permit a woman to remarry without a get because her husband had undergone a sex change surgery and therefore was now considered to be a female

Comment: @wfb On the contrary, IIRC. In that context, he was talking about a case where the sex change was spontaneous, not surgical (10:25:26).

Comment: @Fred He does not seem to distinguish: מחקר גדול יש אמנם לחקור בהיכא שמתחולל שינוי מהותי - אורגני בגופו של אדם כגון בנתהפך מזכר לנקבה או להיפך, וכפי ששמעתי וגם נתפרסם על כך בכתבי-עת שונים, *מבצעים כהיום גם נתוחים כאלה* במקרים מיוחדים. On the Tzitz Eliezer's sources in 18-19th century science, see https://moderntoraleadership.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/science-halakhah-and-the-halakhists-dilemma/

Comment: @wfb That quote is from 10:25:26. The *Tzitz Eliezer* brings up the question of the halachic implications of either a surgical or spontaneous change (in your cited quote), but then he does not end up drawing conclusions about the case of surgical sex change. He also never extrapolates from his discussion of a spontaneous "organic" sex change to the case of a surgical sex change. His later responsum (11:78) suggests that the halachic effectiveness of a sex change operation could extend as far as to the case of an infertile *androginus*, and even then he only entertains that as a possibility.

Comment: I looked up the source, I don't see him quoting a "vast majority of poskim" that disagree with the tzitz Eliezer.
https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems,_Vol_I,_Part_I,_CHAPTER_V_Medical_Questions?lang=en

Comment: @user262055 see here https://moderntoraleadership.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/science-halakhah-and-the-halakhists-dilemma/ where he explains that the Tzitz Eliezer was basing himself on 19th century speculation about the ability of men to spontaneously transform into females, which is not relevant to the question of transgender at all. In fact, R. Bleich has more recently explained that the Tzitz Eliezer himself never intended to discuss a case of transgender surgery at all. Listen here http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/111916-dealing-with-fertility-and-related-issues/

Answer (score 5):

The Tzitz Eliezer is at the end of Vol 10 25:26:6. The teshuvah discusses transplants, and he raises the question posed here as a hypothetical. A second teshuvah, in vol 11 #78, is about someone with a hormonal issue impacting their sexual development during gestation who is born looking female, but has one testicle. In both cases he says that gender is decided by external organs, not internal ones.

I frankly do not know of anyone else who wrote on the topic. Also, notably, REW wrote a teshuvah, i.e. intending to be follows in practice -- lehalakhah ulema'aseh, as opposed to R Bleich's more theoretical journal article.

Speaking theoretically, I could see logic of a third position.... That with regard to halachic gender differences based on role, the person's gender is that of their birth. So that the person in question would still be obligated to wear tefillin, daven three times a day, etc... But when it comes to gender issues related to sexuality, their gender is their new assigned gender. After all, if the person is now female, is yichud with men or with women more problematic? What to do about minyan, which is interpersonal but not sexual, is beyond the scope of my speculation.

Comment: What does gender have to with davening three times a day?

Comment: I keep thinking your profile picture _is_ R Bleich!

Comment: @DoubleAA, he must not hold like the Rav.

Comment: @SethJ Or like some other solitary opinions... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/if-women-are-not-obliged-to-daven-maariv-should-they-daven-if-they-wish-to#comment101317_13326

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard somewhere that women are not chayav to daven Ma'ariv (or Arvit, or Arbit, to cover all my bases).

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot If you heard such a thing it must have been made up in the last ~200 years. No Rishon mentions such a thing, yet they all had women around. They all just say that nowadays Halakha treats Maariv as a Chiyuv.

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard it all the time from school Rebbeim-- If you know Yavneh Academy of Paramus, I could give you names.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot Oh, I don't doubt that you heard such things. I too have heard many people say that. I've even seen a respectable Rabbi/Posek say _in writing_ that all agree to it (which is demonstrably false). It's, frankly, astounding.

Answer (score 4):

I heard that the London Beis Din sometime in the 20th century had such a case and asked [Rabbi Ruderman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yitzchok_Ruderman) if this person could give a get. Rabbi Ruderman didn't discuss if the gender change would have any ramifications on their halachic gender. He responded that even if they are now considered a female, it doesn't say anywhere **a woman can't give their wife a get**. The Torah says **give your wife a get**, and they did.

Whether they are a shotah or not would depend on the case. The case you describe doesn't sound like they're so crazy to me...

Comment: Hey, how did you hear about this case? It'd be interesting to know if it really happened.

Comment: @chachamNisan Rav Ruderman told Rav Shraga Neuberger (or maybe he was around when it happened) who shared it with us. I believe it really happened