# Which side of the mechitza for a transgender individual?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, mechitza-partition, gender-identity

Although this question would understandably require CYLOR in each situation, if a man who had a procedure done to appear similar to a woman, where should such an individual sit in shul? Also, would the halacha be different if a woman had the procedure performed to appear like a man?

Comment: Tricky question. We must first figure out whether or not a transgender person assumes the gender change in halocha. It is very likely that a man who became a transgender woman would remain a man halochically.

Comment: @ezra, in modern understanding, gender is not tied to biological sex, rather, it's tied to the identity of the individual (their neshama if you will). Their are a few aggadetahs and midrashim on the subject IIRC

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Are you defending the idea of transgender people? (Not address hostilely.)

Comment: @ezra, why shouldn't I? Chassidus and kabbalah would give more reason to defend gender as an independent concept from sex than my own hashkafic works would, but there's no good reason not to accept transgender individuals as they are, rather than forcing them to conform to something they're not.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81864/759

Comment: @ezra there's nothing to defend. The people exist whether you agree with them or not. No point in arguing with the Metziut.

Comment: R. J.D. Bleich on the subject http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/111916-dealing-with-fertility-and-related-issues/