# Did the bible make any prediction of what Jewish law should do if a transsexual woman with a real vagina existed?

Tags: marriage

Did the Bible make any predictions of what Jewish marriage law would rule on the subject of a transsexual woman with a real vagina if a Jewish men wanted to or did marry him?

Should Jewish law continue to ban the relationship if tall transsexual women may possibly exist who might be pretty tempting to every Jewish man?

Comment: If you mean to ask what the law is and not about predictions about what will happen, then this is a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34058.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is gender halachically determined?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34058/how-is-gender-halachically-determined)

Comment: to know this there is no need of predictions but to halachic rules, to similar examples as aylonit and androgynos

Comment: ...every Jewish man?  I like my women short.  Well, not too short-but if they tower over me I get nervous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Bible made no such prediction.

Comment: Is it ok that I gave an upvote just because you were able to understand the question well enough to answer it?

Comment: See also my comment on the question. cc @YK

Comment: @YK. I just stuck to reading the title and that made it much simpler.