# According to the Tzitz Eliezer, is transgenderism actually muttar?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, tznius-modesty, modern-times, contemporary-halacha

If I am understanding everything correctly, the Tzitz Eliezer's psak is that if a man get's a surgery that alters his genitals to that of a woman, they assume the halachic status of a woman, and are mechayev to all the mitzvos specific to women (tznius, shabbos candles, etc). And furthermore, this action according to him does not violate the posuk וּמָע֤וּךְ וְכָתוּת֙ וְנָת֣וּק וְכָר֔וּת לֹ֥א תַקְרִ֖יבוּ לַֽיהֹוָ֑ה וּֽבְאַרְצְכֶ֖ם לֹ֥א תַעֲשֽׂוּ׃ because such a person assumedly would have undergone hormone treatments that would have already rendered him impotent by the time of the surgery, meaning that this operation could not at that point be considered castration.

Two questions: One, am I misunderstanding something about this psak? And two, even holding by this psak is undergoing such a process muttar given that it would probably prevent a person from P'ru ur'vu?

Comment: It is a common misconception and misinterpretation of the Tzitz Eliezer to say that he held surgery would alter the halachic sex of a person with a prior biologically definite sex. See [these comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34058/how-is-gender-halachically-determined#comment140528_34060).

Comment: [Shab. 110b-111a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.110b.6?lang=bi), [Rambam Hil. Isurei Bi'ah 16:10-12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960664/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Sixteen.htm).

Comment: Where did you hear this that you seek confirmation of it?

Comment: Men are also obligated in tznius and shabbos candles.

Comment: https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/demystifying-r-eliezer-waldenberg-on-sex-reassignment-surgery

Comment: @robev See the thread I linked to in my above comment. I commented about the article there.

Comment: It isn't even clear the ZE says that gender reassignment surgery would work. He raises a hypothetical case of a woman who is an agunah because her husband, now a woman, refuses to give a get. He suggests this idea as one factor a rabbi could use among many to build a case to free an agunah. (A "s'nif lehaqeil") Not that the probability this works would qualify as a given, or even that it would work if the matter were less painful than the plight of an agunah..