# Davening maariv occasionally without minyan

Tags: halacha, minyan, maariv

The maariv prayer service was originally established as a reshut and that has ramifications in halacha. Does it affect the obligation to pray maariv with a minyan? Perhaps similar to how we can skip parts of psuke desimra occasionally but not regularly, maybe one can pray without a minyan occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to study - in depth - the [Tosafos in Chagiga 9](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01139.html)b which has an analysis of the  status of Maariv as a Reshut, nowadays.

> א**ו תפלה של ערבית.** אתיא כמאן דאמר "תפלת ערבית חובה". ואפילו ל**מאן דאמר "רשות", בחנם אין לנו לבטלה אם לא ע''י אונס קצת**, וכן משמע ההיא דתפלת השחר (ברכות דף כו.) "שכח ולא התפלל ערבית מתפלל שחרית שתים" וכן (שם דף ל:) "אם שכח ולא הזכיר של ר''ח בלילה אין מחזירין אותו לפי שאין מקדשין החדש בלילה", הא "מקדשין" מחזירין. ולא מחלק כלל בין למאן דאמר "רשות" או בין למאן דאמר "חובה", דמשמע דליכא מאן דפליג. וההיא דשבת (דף ט: ושם) "אי שרא ליה הימייניה לא מטרחינן ליה" וכן בירושלמי "אי עלה למטתו לא ירד" היינו אונס קצת. ולא כפירוש ה''ג שפירש' דאף למאן דאמר רשות אי שויה עליה חובה הויא כחובה, והא ליתא, דמי לא עסקינן בהכי שכבר התפלל בשאר 
>   לילות? ואם היינו מפרשים "שויה עליה חובה באותה לילה" יתכן ההיא דטעה ולא התפלל ר''ח בלילה ובברכות הארכתי והבאתי ההיא דאמרו (יומא דף פז: ושם) "דתפלת נעילה פוטרת של 
>   ערבית"
>   :‏

Bottom line - before in-depth analysis - is that (1) not everybody agrees it's Reshut, and (2) even if it is, it's not voluntary, in that you don't have to say it if you don't want to. Only in extenuating circumstances (like you already went to bed) does the *Reshut* kick in.

As to your question: **If you skip the Minyan, you miss out on Borchu and Kaddish and Tefila B'Zibur.**

The first 2 are fulfilments of Mitzvot like ונקדשתי, IRRC.

Tefila B'Zibur has its own merits - like ensuring your Tefila gets answered even if you didn't concentrate properly.

These issues are not connected to Resut - and **missing them is a מעוות לא יוכל לתקון - an irreplaceable loss - as the Gemara there says.**

Comment: I try to fully understand the answer. First of all even that an ones kzat is needed, does not mean that it is a full chova like shacharit and therefore it could be that the halachic ramifications are different. Regarding the second argument of "מעוות לא יוכל לתקון" i don't understand it fully. Surely it is good to hear borchu. The question is if it is a chiyuv to do so. I understand that in a Musser class this is a valid answer but is it also in a halacha class?

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang - I think that was answered well in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12326/501 - including Maariv.

Comment: @Danny Does that answer apply here where the prayer is reshut (whatever that means)

Comment: @DoubleAA - I was assuming that this referred to Maariv, but I guess you could make it refer to a late Mincha.

סעיף טז ההולך בדרך והגיע לעיר ורוצה ללון בה אם לפניו עד ד' מילין מקום שמתפללים בי' צריך לילך שם ולאחריו צריך לחזור עד מיל כדי להתפלל בי':

Comment: I'll just note that even accd to those authorities who claim women never accepted Maariv on themselves as a Chovah, they still have to Daven it every night absent pressing circumstances accd to this.